# LiveCharts: How is the AxisCore internal properties accessible from WpfView Axis implementation?

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm looking through the code of the popular WPF graphing component LiveCharts, in an effort to port it to .NET 3.5. However, I'm not sure how this bit works:

`LiveCharts.AxisCore.TopLimit` is declared as an `internal` property. There are others too declared the same. Then, in `LiveCharts.Wpf.Axis`, a class variable  `public AxisCore Model { get; set; }` is declared, and these internal properties are referenced in various methods, for example in the method `public void SetRange(double min, double max)`.

These are separate assemblies (as far as I can tell), with Core being a portable assembly targeted only at .NET Framework 4. and WpfView a vanilla class library. How can these internal properties be accessible without using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `InternalsVisibleTo`? It's available since .NET 2.0 (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You misunderstand. I'm not writing the code, I'm trying to understand the code in the LiveCharts github repo:https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/master/Core/AxisCore.cs#L198 And I don't understand how these properties could be visible outside of the assembly, hence my question.

Comment: See https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/5709a2e415038d5e6ebb707f48b03927c50babec/Core/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L33-L35

Comment: Right. Thanks! Also, total facepalm moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core Project is using the `InternalsVisibleTo` Attribute in the file `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("LiveCharts.Uwp,PublicKey=002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010009132ae1a474e2ecf9903c1ef8945a2119aa0b9a3b4e40c43f6cb66233669e3007b4109d5c37957c2d0c5cfe7fce34366150210f83c618c18cdc8d7b763bff60419837a2185df1867c73f679e05f82b861e6ca764612eabc36d71858260b262bb9c3ad546c9692fe6379a520b6c5fc701e0ee6d071b52e9f20166fc0752ff894")] 
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("LiveCharts.Wpf,PublicKey=002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010009132ae1a474e2ecf9903c1ef8945a2119aa0b9a3b4e40c43f6cb66233669e3007b4109d5c37957c2d0c5cfe7fce34366150210f83c618c18cdc8d7b763bff60419837a2185df1867c73f679e05f82b861e6ca764612eabc36d71858260b262bb9c3ad546c9692fe6379a520b6c5fc701e0ee6d071b52e9f20166fc0752ff894")] 
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("LiveCharts.Geared,PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100bd2e66fab8ce9a4900047ffda57d2f525cf6313dcc9d20994c5e6b3cd8fca906ba7ccd54bea5f7bd6cb503deb81d685259e355e3a9b5c21e5bc80091f08846246371b2a71ab306655651261e910adfa61be236b77d11df23a44d48f00a0e07c689f9a2daaff16d505a1c861d9854d92ed5a8a38fb28c1343fb691462873e71a1")]
```

See https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/5709a2e415038d5e6ebb707f48b03927c50babec/Core/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L33-L35